# How to set Oracle environment variables for Grid and Database Installation?

Tags: oracle, variables, environment, oracle-enterprise-manager

I'm taking and Oracle course and trying to recover lost ground in Linux, since I've always used Windows.

I have difficulties understanding how to set environment properly for Grid and Database Installation. When I come across that "Choose installation path" screen, I feel tempted to use the standard path and proceed. But I know that's not the best way, since grid needs to be installed on other directory  instead of inside /database.

What are the paths and variables that I need to set?

**for example:**

`/home/oracle/product/xxxxx` is the standard through the wizard, but it should be:

```
/u01/app/oracle.../.../dh_home1

/u01/app/oracle../grid/

export
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, 
Take a look at my `.bash_profile` file of **Oracle** user.
- of course you can set more variables but this ones are quite enough to make your **OEM** install go thru.

```
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=hostname.domian; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=EMR; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u00/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=EMR; export ORACLE_SID
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
ORASID=EMR; export ORASID

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH

#Enterprise Manager Settings
OMS_HOME=/u00/oms12.0.3/oms; export OMS_HOME
AGENT_HOME=/u00/agent12.0.3/core/12.1.0.3.0; export AGENT_HOME

#aliases used for OEM management
alias scr="cd /home/oracle/scripts"
alias oms="cd /u00/oms12.0.3/oms/bin"
alias agent="cd /u00/agent12.0.3/core/12.1.0.3.0/bin"
alias omslog="tail -f /u00/oms12.0.3/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/log/emctl.log"
```

I suggest you create new paths for the installation and name them as you like. This is only to make your life easier after.
[For more articles on how to setup and manager you Oracle Enterprise Manager environment see this link. I update the site quite often :)](http://www.aodba.com/pt/blog/2014/12/09/startstop-script-oracle-enterprise-manager-12c/)

I hope this helped !

Comment: Thanks Up_One. I think it worked just fine following the instructions of your file. I am now having some other issues, with missing packages, which I posted on another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919176/oracle-grid-installation-missing-packages-compat-libcap1-1-10-and-others - Thanks again!!!

Comment: what is you OS version and your grid version ?