# Oracle Grid Installation - Missing Packages compat-libcap1-1.10 and others

Tags: oracle, grid, package

There are a few packages missing and they show up as non-fixable on Oracle Grid Installation wizard.

Missing Packages:

```
Package: compat-libcap1-1.10
Package: compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3(x86_64)
Package : libstdc++-devel-4.4.4(x86_64)
Package: gcc-c++-4.4.4
Package: ksh-20100621
Package: libaio-devel-0.3.107
```

Were this packages suppose to come built-in with OS? I'm running Oracle Linux 6 on Virtual Box.

Is there a way to install all of them at once or will I need to search and install one by one?

Thanks.

Comment: here is the prereqs pkgs - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_packages.htm#CHDEJAFA

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to do a clean  install is using  `EM Prerequisite Kit` that is available in the following location of the software kit:

```
<Download_Location>/install/requisites/bin/emprereqkit
```

Run this script in case o a fresh install.